# Det neighbours within radius of each point , radius changes per point relating to c value. Sk-learn to slow anything faster?

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, brute-force, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I am working on a point cloud simplification algorithm that preserves features.

In the one aspect I am searching through each xyzc point,  at each point i search the nearest neighbours within a radius - this radius is related to the points c value.

I have been using sk-learn nearest neighbours but it is super slow!!!

Is there any other library I can use that is much faster?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If exact nearest neighbors search is too slow you should probably try approximate nearest neighbors search instead, for instance using the [flann](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/) library.

Comment: Hi @ogrisel i am having difficulties installing flann for python

Comment: Installing Flann for python
source:W:/Work/UCT/flann-1.8.4-src66/flann-1.8.4-src binaries: C:/Python27/Lib generator: Visual Studio 12 compiler identification is unknown The CXX compiler identification is unknown Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:76 (message): hdf5 library not found, some tests will not be run @ogrisel

Comment: In general you'd better report installation issues on the flann project issue tracker or by contacting its author. But in this case it's just a matter of reading the error message: install the HDF5 library on your system first.

Comment: thanks will do, where should my source point to and where should my binaries point to? thanks i'm new in the field. learning by trial and error